# Use pd.read_csv(), specified data as np.float32, but got string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I tried to read the data from a csv file. I want to set the 'Data' column's datatype as 
float, so my code is like:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, 
                   parse_dates=[0], 
                   skiprows=[0], names=['Data'],
                   dtype={'Data':np.float32})
```

But the result I got is still list of strings. Is there any reason and any solution for it?

```
[5]: data.values

[5]: array([['1188.0'],
            ['1377.0'],
            ['1279.0'],
            ['1461.0'],
            ['1146.0'],
            ['1287.0'],
            ['1259.0']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add value to `names` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

temp="""2019-01-02,1188.0
2019-01-03,1377.0
2019-01-04,1279.0
2019-01-05,1461.0
2019-01-06,1146.0
2019-01-07,1287.0
2019-01-08,1259.0"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                 index_col=0,
                 parse_dates=[0],
                 names=['dates','Data'],
                 dtype={'Data':np.float32})
```

---

```
print (df)
              Data
dates             
2019-01-02  1188.0
2019-01-03  1377.0
2019-01-04  1279.0
2019-01-05  1461.0
2019-01-06  1146.0
2019-01-07  1287.0
2019-01-08  1259.0

print (df.dtypes)
Data    float32
dtype: object

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05',
               '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='dates', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually the csv file includes 2 columns: date and data. If I remove the parse_date, I can have the correct datatype. So does it means that I couldn't achieve both in one line? Does the parse_date function conflicts with the datatype specification? Thanks!

Comment: @Kid - So I think you need `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, names=['Data'], dtype={'Data':np.float32})`

Comment: @Kid - Solution was changed completely.